# External Command Error on VHCS Installation

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have  Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) server and i'm trying to install [VHCS](http://www.vhcs.net) . I'm following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VHCS) steps but on last steps of the **Configuration Script** title i'm executing **vhcs2-setup** . After last question (*Please enter admininistrator email address*) when i press ENTER i'm getting this error :

```
Use of uninitialized value $fgid in getgrnam at ./vhcs2-setup line 799, <STDIN> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $cfg{"CMD_GROUPADD"} in concatenation (.) or string at ./vhcs2-setup line 803, <STDIN> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $fgid in concatenation (.) or string at ./vhcs2-setup line 803, <STDIN> line 8.
ERROR: External command ' ' returned '255' status !
```

I'm googled it, but couldn't find anything.